# Date attribute format Weka

Tags: date, datetime, weka, arff

I have imported an Arff file structured in this way:

```
@relation pv_italy 
@attribute idsito numeric 
@attribute data date "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
@attribute id.x numeric 
@attribute anno numeric 
@data 
1,"2012-01-01 02:00:00",1,2012
```

After that I imported the file, in "Selected Attribute" panel the "date" attribute isn't in the form "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but in milliseconds. 
I use Weka 3.9.1.
I would know how should i do to visualize the date in the format that i defined in the arff file.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As this post states weka saves a time as a numeric (milliseconds).

http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/ChangeDateFormat-td3059.html

As i understood understood you only (1) could save Year Month and Day as Nominals in an extra column.

Or (2) apply a Filter but like another Stackoverflow answer says that's meaningless for the power of your data.

[Weka attribute date doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903104/weka-attribute-date-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but might help others. It worked for me. Just change your attribute declaration to 
`@attribute Date date`
and then enter your values as 
`2012-01-01T02:00:00`
no need for quotes